# Ranging for iBeacons in the background based on proximity

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, ibeacon

The `SDK` of `Estimote` allows users to range for `beacons` based on `proximity` even when the app is in the `background`. `Apple` only allows it to range for `beacons` based on `proximity` on the `foreground`. My question is, is there a way to mimic `Estimote` when it comes to range with a `proximity` in the `background`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apple's CoreLocation framework actually does allow you to range in the background**, but the time you are allowed to do so is limited to 10 seconds after the app transitions to the background.  You can extend this to 180 seconds upon request, or indefinitely if you put background location mode in your Info.plist.

Read more here:  http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios

Comment: Do you maybe have some code or an example in swift that demonstrates how to indefinitely range for beacons with the background location mode?